# How do I include info from two queries in same resulting table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following queries:

```
select year, avg(value) as winter_avg_Miami from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) ='killowatts' and  substring(series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') group by year;
select year, avg(value) as winter_avg_notMiami from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) = 'killowatts' and  substring(series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami' and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') group by year;
```

What I want to do is instead of getting two different tables, one like:

```
year       winter_avg_Miami
2000             28.1
2001             30.2
```

and another table like:

```
year        winter_avg_notMiami
2000             40.1
2001             50.2
```

I want to just have all the info in one table such as:

```
year       winter_avg_Miami  winter_avg_notMiami
2000             28.1              40.1 
2001             30.2              50.2
```

How can i write my query in order to accomplish this?

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. you'd be better off with just a single query, and `group by substring(seris_id, 3,5) = 'Miami', year`, then transforming the records to columns in client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement in your `avg` aggregate:

```
select year, 
   avg(case when substring(series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' then value end) as winter_avg_Miami,
   avg(case when substring(series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami' then value end) as winter_avg_notMiami 
from AP_DATA 
where substring(series_id, 8) ='killowatts'
    and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') 
group by year
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c1c6/1)

Comment: worked perfectly, and best of all very readable/easy to understand. exactly what i was looking for! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      year,
      case when CntMiami = 0 then 0 else TotMiami / CntMiami end ) as AvgMiami,
      case when CntNotMiami = 0 then 0 else TotNotMiami / CntNotMiamt end ) as AvgNotMiami
from
   (
select 
      year, 
      sum( case when substring(series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' then value else 0 end ) as TotMiami,
      sum( case when substring(series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' then 1 else 0 end ) as CntMiami,
      sum( case when substring(series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami' then value else 0 end ) as TotNotMiami,
      sum( case when substring(series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami' then 1 else 0 end ) as CntNotMiami
   from 
      AP_DATA 
   where 
          substring(series_id, 8) ='killowatts' 
      and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') 
   group by 
      year )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are correct, this should work:

```
SELECT a.year, a.winter_avg_Miami, b.winter_avg_notMiami
From (select year, avg(value) as winter_avg_Miami 
     from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) ='killowatts' and  
         substring(series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') 
     group by year)a, 
    (select year, avg(value) as winter_avg_notMiami 
    from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) = 'killowatts' and  
    substring(series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami' and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') 
    group by year) b
WHERE a.year = b.year;
```

Comment: worked great, i was trying so many variations of my query trying to achieve exactly this but i couldn't figure it out! you helped me understand proper formatting for these type of queries as well as using aliases. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

[UNIONS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) are a simple alternative if there is some reason you can't do one of the more traditional ways like sgeddes suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Solutions :

**solution : 1**

```html
select ap1.year, avg(ap1.value) as winter_avg_Miami,avg(ap2.value) as winter_avg_notMiami
from AP_DATA ap1 left join ap2.AP_DATA on ap1.year=ap2.year
where substring(ap1.series_id, 8) ='killowatts' and  substring(ap1.series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' and ap1.period IN ('M10','M11','M12') 
substring(ap2.series_id, 8) = 'killowatts' and  substring(ap2.series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami'and ap2.period IN ('M10','M11','M12')
group by ap1.year;
```

**Solution : 2**

```html
--create temp table
create table temp1
(year int, winter_avg_Miami int null,winter_avg_notMiami int null)

--insert into temp table
insert into temp1
(year int, winter_avg_Miami ,winter_avg_notMiami)
(
select year, avg(value) as winter_avg_Miami,null as winter_avg_notMiami from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) ='killowatts' and  substring(series_id, 3,5) = 'Miami' and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') group by year
union all
select year, null as winter_avg_Miami, avg(value) as winter_avg_notMiami from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) = 'killowatts' and  substring(series_id, 3,5) != 'Miami' and period IN ('M10','M11','M12') group by year
)

--result in single table
select year,avg(winter_avg_Miami) as winter_avg_Miami,avg(winter_avg_notMiami) as winter_avg_notMiami
from temp1
group by year
```

I tried above solutions in sybase. it worked fine.

Hope this helps :)